# Custom email address attribute on client side

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, client-side-validation, validationattribute

Evening all!

I've created the below validation attribute to check a list of emails are valid.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Parameter)]
public class EmailAddressListAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    private const string RegexPattern = @"[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*" +
                                        @"@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?";

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        ErrorMessage = $"{validationContext.DisplayName} contains invalid email addresses";

        var emailList = value.ToString().Split(';');
        return emailList.Where(e => !IsValidEmail(e))
            .ToList()
            .Count == 0 ? null : new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
    }

    private static bool IsValidEmail(string emailAddress)
    {
        return Regex.IsMatch(emailAddress, RegexPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        yield return new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage,
            ValidationType = "emailaddresslist"
        };
    }
}
```

I want to be able to utilize this on the client side but I'm unsure how I go about doing this. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Z

EDIT

I've added the below JS code as a file and I'm rendering it on my view. It's running on page load but doesn't seem to do anything when submit the form.

```
(function ($) {
$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addSingleVal("emailaddresslist");

$.validator.addMethod("emailaddresslist", function (value, element, params) {
    return false;
});
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: are you using unobtrusive validation?

Comment: You need to write scripts for the client side validation. Suggest you read [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2).

Comment: I've tried adding the above javascript but it's not firing on submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working! Here's the code for my attribute

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class EmailAddressListAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    private const string DefaultErrorMessage = "{0} contains invalid email addresses.";
    private const string RegexPattern = @"[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*" +
                                        @"@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?";

    public EmailAddressListAttribute()
      : base(DefaultErrorMessage)
    {
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return string.Format(ErrorMessageString, name);
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        ErrorMessage = $"{validationContext.DisplayName} contains invalid email addresses";

        if (value.ToString().IsNullOrWhiteSpace()) return null;

        var emailList = value.ToString().Split(';');

        return emailList.Where(e => !IsValidEmail(e))
            .ToList()
            .Count == 0 ? null : new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var clientValidationRule = new ModelClientValidationRule()
        {
            ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName()),
            ValidationType = "emailaddresslist"
        };

        clientValidationRule.ValidationParameters.Add("otherproperty", "");

        return new[] { clientValidationRule };
    }

    private static bool IsValidEmail(string emailAddress)
    {
        return Regex.IsMatch(emailAddress, RegexPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    }
}
```

And here's the jquery that does the client side.

```
(function ($) {
$.validator.addMethod("emailaddresslist", function (value, element, params) {
    if (!this.optional(element)) {
        if (value == "") return true;
        var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        var emailAddressList = value.split(";")
        var arrayLength = emailAddressList.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            if (!re.test(emailAddressList[i].trim())) return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
});
$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addSingleVal("emailaddresslist", "otherproperty");
}(jQuery));
```